# Problems Summing 2 Values in an Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sum two cells in a macro using

```
Dim test1 As Variant, test2 As Variant
test1 = UsedRows.Offset(i, 25).Value
test2 = UsedRows.Offset(i, 26).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = test1 + test2
```

But Im getting a type mismatch error. If I make the value equal to just test1 or just test2 it works, but it breaks when I try to add them together (gives a type mismatch error). Ive searched around but cant find a solution

Comment: in IDE put breakpoint (F9) in `Activecell...` line and hoover with mouse over your `test1` & `test2` variables to check their values. What are these values?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine so long as the cells are either empty or numeric, if there is any other value you will get an error. You can check and handle these errors using something like:

```
If Not IsNumeric(test1) Then
```